# My mother is forcing me not to fast during my exams

Tags: sawm, family

My mother thinks I'll mess up my exams if I fast. If i do fast on exam day, she might get extremely angry at me and also worried. Yesterday she explained it might affect her health if I do fast because of how worried she will be. Should I obey her or fast on that day?

Comment: Also is it selfish if I fast despite knowing it will hurt my mother and worry her?

Comment: The most important input we need to answer is are you mature is fast compulsory on you?

Comment: @Medi1Saif  I’m assuming fast is compulsory as its exam time in UK so if this student is from the UK where they are doing their GCSEs or A-levels then they would be 15-18 but if not, it’s still mostly likely that this person is of fasting age if they are doing exams.

Comment: Yes i am 18. So it is obligatory for me. I want to avoid a big fight with my mom but I feel like she won't listen no matter what i say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not required to obey your parents in sin. If fasting is prescribed for you (i.e: you have no significant health complication, you are pubescent, you are not menstruating etc) you should fast.
Your mother will learn to accept it once it becomes normal for her, remember that people used to fight wars while fasting.

Comment: Update: so last night i woke up for suhoor, my mom was up and she tried to convince me not to fast as i had my math exam today. I tried to explain to her that i'll be fine, i've been doing well on my self-mocks and that i haven't been having problems with concentrating. She started to cry and said i didnt give any value to her opinions despite her doing a lot for me.. it felt wrong to hurt her and then keep fasting. What would be the right thing to do?

Comment: @Someone She's an adult, she'll get over it. Perhaps consider other areas where you don't respect your mothers opinion however. Also where's your dad in all this?

Answer (score 0):

Fasting is the most important obligation of Muslims and they have to fast. But in your case if you are adult and having fast is obligation on you then you have to fast no matter its your exams time or any other important task. You should fast and also try to get good grades in your exams so your mother will be satisfied and will not consider fast as a burden or any other mess for your exams. And you should also satisfy your mother by telling her that you Islam as our religion comes first and first we have to fulfill all obligations of being a Muslim. So provide her a comfort zone and then she will remain calm and would not be worried about you.